# How can I prevent (subclass of Ember._MetamorphView)?

Tags: ember.js

According to [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168239/item-specific-actions-in-ember-js-collection-views), using {{view}} within {{each}} is the right way to display a view for each element of an array (the thread is quite old, though).

Now my problem is that this method generates *(subclass of **Ember._MetamorphView**)* instead of *(subclass of **MyApp.MyView**)* and makes it impossible for me to call some specific methods later, defined in *MyApp.MyView*, it says:

```
Object <(subclass of Ember._MetamorphView):ember381> has no method 'play'
```

I know there are other ways to achieve the same goal, like *{{collection}}* or *Ember.ContainerView*, or even *Ember.ArrayController*. But if not really necessary, I really like to stay simple using the {{each}} approach.

Is there a way to prevent *(subclass of Ember._MetamorphView)* and have my own class?

Comment: could you post a jsfiddle or jsbin with an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of trying stuff out, I gave it up and did it using a collection:

```
{{#collection App.AnswersView contentBinding="answers"}}
  <div class="answer alpha">{{view.content.answer}}</div>
{{/collection}}
```