# Item specific actions

Tags: ember.js

Against my controller, I have an item with an array of items which I want to display a list of and have an action to remove an item.

Have taken most of the code from a similar question [item-specific actions in ember.js collection views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168239/item-specific-actions-in-ember-js-collection-views). Majority of this works, the address display works and the items render, however the action does not seem to have the correct context and therefore does not perform the remove action.

Controller:

```
App.EditAddressesController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    temporaryUser: {
        firstName: 'Ben', 
        lastName: 'MacGowan', 
        addresses: [{
            number: '24', 
            city: 'London'
            etc...
        }, {
            number: '23', 
            city: 'London'
            etc...
        }]
    }
});
```

The temporaryUser is an EmberObject (based off a User model), and each item within the addresses array is another EmberObject (based off an Address model) - this has just been simplified for purposes of displaying code.

Parent view:

```
{{#each address in temporaryUser.addresses}}
    {{#view App.AddressView addressBinding="this"}}
        {{{address.display}}}
        <a {{action deleteAddress target="view"}} class="delete">Delete</a>
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

App.AddressView:

```
App.AddressView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li', 
    address: null, 
    deleteAddress: function() {
        var address = this.get('address'), 
        controller = this.get('controller'), 
        currentAddresses = controller.get('temporaryUser.addresses');
        if(currentAddresses.length > 1) {
            $.each(currentAddresses, function(i) {
                if(currentAddresses[i] == address) {
                    currentAddresses.splice(i, 1);
                }
             });
        }
        else {
            //Throw error saying user must have at least 1 address
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out it was an issue with my each:

```
{{#each address in temporaryUser.addresses}}
```

should have been:

```
{{#each temporaryUser.addresses}}
```

And my AddressView should use removeObject (like the original code sample)

```
App.AddressView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li', 
    address: null, 
    deleteAddress: function() {
        var address = this.get('address'), 
        controller = this.get('controller'), 
        currentAddresses = controller.get('temporaryUser.addresses');
        if(currentAddresses.length > 1) {
            currentAddresses.removeObject(address);
        }
        else {
            //Throw error saying user must have at least 1 address
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code could become more readable if you approach it that way:

1- **Modify your action helper to pass the address with it as context.** I modified your Handlebars a bit to reflect the way i am approaching stuff like this and works for me. I think this is the "Ember way" of doing this kind of stuff, since a the properties in a template are always a lookup against the context property of the corresponding view:

```
{{#each address in temporaryUser.addresses}}
    {{#view App.AddressView contextBinding="address"}}
        {{{display}}}
        <!-- this now refers to the context of your view which should be the address -->
        <a {{action deleteAddress target="view" this}} class="delete">Delete</a>
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

2 - **Modify the handler in your view to accept the address as a parameter:**

```
App.AddressView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li', 
    address: null, 
    deleteAddress: function(address) {
        var controller = this.get('controller'), 
        currentAddresses = controller.get('temporaryUser.addresses');
        if(currentAddresses.length > 1) {
            currentAddresses.removeObject(address);
        }
        else {
            //Throw error saying user must have at least 1 address
        }
    }
});
```